# Addition of http in URL of website

Tags: url, web

When I browse a website like www.google.com, is it the browser that adds the http in front of it to make http://www.google.com, or does the initial request go without the protocol name ?

I tried it on a ubuntu machine using apache web server for a locally hosted URL.
I find that the initial packets are a TCP handshake, and then the request is for http://www.example.com. Did the initial TCP SYN packet also try to go to http://www.example.com OR just www.example.com ?

P.S. In Wireshark, the TCP SYN packet has no HTTP header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser adds it. Different browsers have different logic on how to parse a invalid URL into a proper one. For example, if you type plain words, some browsers return an error page, while others open a search page (e.g. google or bing). Same thing happens with incomplete URLs (e.g. without http: schema)

The overall process is like this:

1. user types the "URL"
2. browser tries parse and fix (if needed) the URL (e.g. add http for new address, add https for sites using https that are in browse history, prepare a search/error page for invalid input, etc)
3. browser does a DNS lookup for the domain of the URL (e.g. convert www.example.com to 93.184.216.119)
4. browser sets up a TCP connection to 93.184.216.119 to the port indicated in the URL or that implied from the schema (e.g. 80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS). TCP doesn't know/care about the schema.
5. for HTTPS, browsers negociates the SSL session.
6. browser sends the HTTP request and gets the reply.

Comment: Ok so the TCP SYN packet went to `http://www.example.com` ? I ask because in wireshark on the ubuntu machine, there is no HTTP header in that packet

Comment: TCP SYN (part of TCP 3-way handshake) is just the TCP comunication setup. Only after this is completed, the browser will send the HTTP header (that would normally be the 4th TCP packet, comming after SYN ACK).

Answer (score 1):

`http://` specifies the application-layer protocol.  If no protocol is specified, browsers will generally assume HTTP.  Other possibilities include `ftp://` or (no longer supported by modern browsers) `gopher://`.

TCP is a lower level than HTTP.  At the point when a TCP connection is established, the application-layer protocol doesn't matter.  The only thing that `http://` indicates from the perspective of TCP is the default port number to use if none is specified explicitly.  HTTP defaults to port 80, FTP defaults to port 21, etc.  The browser doesn't start speaking HTTP (or FTP, or whatever) until after the TCP session has been established.